# Android "Undo" doesn't work for android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo

Tags: android, listview, swipe

I am using [android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo](https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo/issues) to have swipe to delete gmail efect.

**setOnItemClickListener** doesn't work for me. Is this because I use in my adapter **OnLongClickListener** and **setOnCheckedChangeListener**?

Implementation of swipe to dismiss:

```
final SwipeToDismissTouchListener<ListViewAdapter> touchListener =
            new SwipeToDismissTouchListener<>(
                    new ListViewAdapter(listItems),
                    new SwipeToDismissTouchListener.DismissCallbacks<ListViewAdapter>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(ListViewAdapter view, int position) {
// here I delete my item. This works perfectly.
                        }
                    });
    listItems.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    listItems.setOnScrollListener((AbsListView.OnScrollListener) touchListener.makeScrollListener());
    listItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (touchListener.existPendingDismisses()) {
                touchListener.undoPendingDismiss();
                Toast.show(MyFragment.this, "x"); // toast never appears
            } else {
                Toast.show(MyFragment.this, "y"); // toast never appears
            }
        }
    });
```

My adapter:

```
public class ShoppingItemsCheckListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public interface OnCheckItemListener {
    public void onCheckItem(ShoppingItem item, boolean isCheck);}

private List<ShoppingItem> shoppingItemsList = new ArrayList<ShoppingItem>();
public OnCheckItemListener onCheckItemListener;

private OnItemShoppingListLongListener onItemShoppingListLongListener = null;

public interface OnItemShoppingListLongListener {
    public void onEditItem(ShoppingItem item);}

public ShoppingItemsCheckListAdapter(OnItemShoppingListLongListener onItemShoppingListLongListener, OnCheckItemListener onCheckItemListener) {
    this.onCheckItemListener = onCheckItemListener;
    this.onItemShoppingListLongListener = onItemShoppingListLongListener;}

public void setModel(List<ShoppingItem> shoppingItemsList) {
    this.shoppingItemsList = shoppingItemsList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();}

@Override
public int getCount() {return shoppingItemsList.size();}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {return shoppingItemsList.get(position);}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {return position;}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_shopping_item, parent, false);
    final ShoppingItem item = shoppingItemsList.get(position);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_shopping_item_check);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            onCheckItemListener.onCheckItem(item, isChecked);
        }
    });
    checkBox.setChecked(item.getCheck());
    checkBox.setText(item.getLabel());
    checkBox.setOnLongClickListener(new OnClickEditItemListener(item));
    return convertView;
}

private class OnClickEditItemListener implements View.OnLongClickListener {
    private ShoppingItem item;
    public OnClickEditItemListener(ShoppingItem item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if (onItemShoppingListLongListener != null) {
            onItemShoppingListLongListener.onEditItem(item);
        }
        return true;
    }}}
```

Is there a way to use OnItemClickListener, OnLongClickListener and OnCheckedChangeListener all together?